# watir-webdriver API documentation (Classes, Methods etc. list)

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I want know where comprehensive list of APIs of watir-webdriver related to browser, elements is located. I am looking something like: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is: http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/frames

Comment: Thanks Zeljko. But where to get the details like the params passed to the method and what are the return values etc....

Comment: A majority of the methods are for HTML elements, the parameters passed are a hash of ':how => "what"' pairs used to identify the instance of the element you are seeing, what is returned is an object of that type, containing whatever sub-elements are wrapped by it in the dom.  If you understand HTML then it's all pretty much 'least surprise' stuff.  Plurel forms return collections of those objects.  stuff that causes the page to refresh like click, returns the time to get the new page.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Rdoc that Zelkjo linked, your other best way to understand how stuff works (aside from the tutorials and the wiki etc) would be to review the tests in watirspec, since they basically document how everything is expected to work. https://github.com/watir/watirspec

Answer (score 1):

API Documentation:

For [watir-webdriver](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/)

For [watir-classic](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-classic)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @matsjoyce: Thanks for your suggestion. I agree with you. But it is very difficult to mention/highlight the essential parts for API doc.

Comment: Just put the relevant section in a blockquote.